# Mean first passage time in an infinite continuous time Markov Chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

[image: Markov Chain]

I want to find the mean first passage time from a state $(1,i)$ to any absorbing state $(0,j)$ in this continuous time Markov chain ($\lambda, \mu$ are transition rates), denoted by $m(1,i)$. I intended to start with the following recursion

$$m(1,i)=\frac{1}{\lambda+\mu}+\frac{\mu}{\lambda+\mu}m(0,i)+\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}m(1,i+1)=\frac{1}{\lambda+\mu}+\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}m(1,i+1).$$

But I am not sure what to do next because there are not a finite number of equations.

Comment: Are you sure about your recursion? Starting in state $(1,i)$ there's an initial (rate $\lambda+\mu$ exponential) waiting time in $i$, followed by a move to state $(1,i+1)$ (with probability $\lambda/(\lambda+\mu)$) or by absorption (with probability $\mu/(\lambda+\mu)$. This would suggest
$$
m(1,i) ={1\over\lambda+\mu}+{\lambda\over\lambda+\mu}m(i+1,1).
$$
Also, because the rates don't depend on  $i$, it seems clear that $m(1,i) = m(1,0)$ for all $i\ge 1$.

Comment: Oops typo... Edited. I think the answer should be $1/\mu$ too, as implied from your statement "because the rates don't depend on $i$....." but is there any "concrete" mathematical proof for that?

Comment: The distribution of your chain (call it $X_t$) started in $X_0=(1,i+1)$ is the same as the distribution of $X_t+(0,1)$ started in $X_0=(1,i)$.

Comment: Hmm sorry, but I think I haven't got your idea... Could you please expain a little bit more in an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to elaborate @John Dawkins's answer since it looks right. From your equation,

$$m(1,i)=\frac{1}{\lambda+\mu}+\frac{\mu}{\lambda+\mu}m(0,i)+\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}m(1,i+1)=\frac{1}{\lambda+\mu}+\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}m(1,i+1)$$
Letting $$m(1,i) = m(1,i+1) = m(1,i+2) = \cdots = m(1, n) = M$$
since the mean first passage time to an absorbing state is the same, regardless of where you are. Say, you start in state (1,1), the mean first passage time is the same as when you start at (1, 10) or (1,100) or (1, n). So simplifying your equation,
$$M = \frac{1}{\lambda+\mu}+\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}M$$
$$M = \frac{1}{\mu}$$